# Python inbuilt fuction os.path.dirname(path) giving inconsistant output?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
os.path.dirname("C:\\myfile\test.h")
```

gives result

```
'C:\\' as dir name
```

Whereas

```
os.path.diranme("C:\\myfile\mytest.h")
```

gives result

```
'C:\\myfile'
```

How to get 2nd output all the times ?
Using python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"C:\\myfile\test.h"` is equivalent to `"C:\\myfile[tab character]est.h"`. Its directory is `"C:\\"` and its file name is `"myfile[tab character]est.h"`.

If you want the file with name `"test.h"` and directory `"C:\\myfile"`, you should escape that backslash:  `"C:\\myfile\\test.h"`. Alternatively, use raw strings: `r"C:\myfile\test.h"`. Alternatively, use "/" if your OS supports it: `"C:/myfile/test.h"`

`"C:\\myfile\mytest.h"` does not share this problem because `\m` is not a valid escape sequence, so Python interprets it as a backslash and an M.

Comment: So if we are inputing it from commandline as an input we should add '\' everywhere in our user input path before we process it ?

Comment: @niyant, if you mean you're inputting a path using `raw_input`, no. The backslashes will be escaped for you. If your code is `os.path.dirname(raw_input("enter filename"))` and the user enters `c:\myfile\test.h`, it will correctly determine the directory name as `c:\myfile`. The same is true for input given via `sys.argv`.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explaination